# How to start adb on usb and ethernet simultaneously

Tags: android, usb, adb, ethernet

By default adb listen on usb. If i enable ethernet by setting persist.adb.tcp.port or service.adb.tcp.port then adb listen only on ethernet. by I'm interested in both connection

Any ideas?

Comment: ...how are you connecting to Android devices via ethernet?

Comment: Do you mean over wi-fi?  I have not heard of an Android device that physically has an Ethernet port.  Sorry if this isn't exactly on topic, I am just curious.

Comment: I have few different android devices with physical Ethernet port (RJ45).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible via current adbd. This features require modification and replacing of adbd.